# What happened to the rest of the Animaniacs cast?

Tags: character, animaniacs

In the 2020 *Animaniacs* cartoon only the three Warner siblings and Pinky & The Brain (as well as one other cameo in the final episode) are featured. All the other old characters like Slappy Squirrel, Minerva Mink, Mindy, Buttons, Goodfeathers, Chicken Boo, The Hip Hippos, Rita and Runt, etc. are gone.

Why are they not back?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they wanted to update the show for current settings, so many characters got removed and even updated. From [AV Club](https://tv.avclub.com/you-wont-find-hello-nurse-in-hulus-new-animaniacs-reboo-1845712268)

> Wellesley Wild, tells us in the video above, when they started rethinking the show for 2020, “Immediately Hello Nurse was Goodbye Nurse.” Wild says the show also updated the characters a bit more, with Dot relying more on her wit and intelligence than she had in the past, flexing, as Wild says, “her feminist muscles a little bit more.” Still, he says, the reboot pushes as far as it’s able, “up to the line of standards and practices” and what “legal would allow us to do.”